# Javascript Login System checks if ("UserPassword") == Undefined not working

Tags: javascript

So basically in an html file, I have an input field, with the id "UserPassword".
In my .js file I have a function register() where it checks if you are Registered, and if not, if this is your first time logging in. If not, then it checks if your inputted password == undefined. If it does, it says "Invalid Username or Password." in the console log.

How I've set it up is that when the function register() is run, when it gets down to the (FirstTimeLoggedIn == "No" else statement, it does
if ("UserPassword" = undefined"), then it will tell you "Invalid Username or Password. Problem is, it doesn't do that, properly. **Regardless of if I have entered a password into the input, it still says "Invalid Username or Password"**

Here's the code: The whole script, seeing as it's not much else besides a login and logout button. And yes, I'm planning on implementing this to the login button as-well, but I needed to get this working first.

````
var Date = Date()
let Username = undefined
let Password = undefined
let LoggedIn = "No"
let CorrectPassword = undefined
let FirstTimeLoggingIn = "Yes"
let Registered = "No"
let ConsoleMessage = undefined

//Hello Message
console.log("Welcome to the Cosmic Online Interactable Interface, or COII.");
ConsoleMessage = "Welcome to Cosmic."
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = (ConsoleMessage);

//Registration Function                                                  
function register() {                                                 
    if (Registered == "Yes") {
        console.log("Already Registered");
        ConsoleMessage = "Already Registered."
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = (ConsoleMessage)
    } 
    else if (FirstTimeLoggingIn == "No") {
            console.log("Account Already Registered.");
        ConsoleMessage = "Account Already Registered.";
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = (ConsoleMessage);
        }
         else {
            document.getElementById("UserPassword".value)
                if  ("UserPassword" == undefined) {
        console.log("Invalid Username or Password.");
        ConsoleMessage = "Invalid Username or Password.";
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = (ConsoleMessage);
                }
            
                 else {
            console.log("Registered at: " + Date);
            Username = document.getElementById("UserUsername").value;
            Password = document.getElementById("UserPassword").value;
            console.log("Welcome, " + Username);
        ConsoleMessage = "Welcome, " + Username;
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = (ConsoleMessage);
        Registered = "Yes";
        FirstTimeLoggingIn = "No";
        LoggedIn = "Yes";
        CorrectPassword = Password;
        //redirect to account page
        setTimeout(() => {  window.location.href = "Home.html"; }, 2000);
        console.log("Redirecting to Home Page");
        ConsoleMessage = "Redirecting to Home Page";
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = (ConsoleMessage);
         }
        }
    }


//Login Function  // Login is WIP

function login() {
    if (Registered == "No") {
     console.log("Not Registered.");
     ConsoleMessage = "Not Registered."
     document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = (ConsoleMessage)
    }
    if (LoggedIn == "Yes") {
        console.log("Already Logged In, " + Username);
           ConsoleMessage = "Already Logged In, " + Username
           document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = (ConsoleMessage)
        }
    
    if (Registered == "Yes" && LoggedIn == "No")
     {
         //if (LoggedIn == "No")
        console.log("Welcome, " + Username);
        ConsoleMessage = "Welcome, " + Username
        console.log("Logged In At: " + Date)
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = (ConsoleMessage)
        LoggedIn = "Yes"
        //redirect to account page
        setTimeout(() => {  window.location.href = "home.html"; }, 2000);
        console.log("Redirecting to Home Page");
        ConsoleMessage = "Redirecting to Home Page";
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = (ConsoleMessage);
     }
}

//Log Out Function.
function LogOut() {
if (LoggedIn == "No") {
    console.log("Not Logged In.");
        ConsoleMessage = "Not Logged In."
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = (ConsoleMessage)
} else {
    LoggedIn = "Yes"
    console.log("Logged Out " + Username);
        ConsoleMessage = "Logged Out " + Username;
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = (ConsoleMessage)
        LoggedIn = "No"
        console.log("Logged Out At: " + Date)
    }
}```
````

Comment: ``"UserPassword" == undefined`` You are checking a ``string`` with a ``undefined``. It will never be true

Comment: @NotABot So, what would I need to write to make "UserPassword" only let you make an account if the password is not undefined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the user left any input field empty, then mostly the value will be `empty`, which means that if you use the `length` property on your input you will get **zero** as the length of the input by the user.

Checking for `NULL` or `undefined` is not much required here, but still, you can check for the same if you want.

```js
document.getElementById("register-user").addEventListener("click", register);

function register() {


  let userName = document.getElementById("user-name");
  let userPassword = document.getElementById("user-password");

  if (userName.value == undefined || 
      userName.value == null || 
      userName.value.length == 0) {

          console.log("Please provide user name");
  }
  else if (userPassword.value == undefined || 
           userPassword.value == null || 
           userPassword.value.length == 0) {
 
             console.log("Please provide user password");
  }
  else {
      console.log("Everything is fine. You can register user.");  
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="user-name" placeholder="Enter User Name" />
<br /><br />
<input type="password" id="user-password" placeholder="Enter User Password" />
<br /><br />
<button id="register-user">Register</button>
```

If you like to reduce some lines of code, you can use the **exclamation mark** (`!`) symbol, called a **bang**, which is the logical `NOT` operator.

You can replace

```
 userName.value == undefined || 
 userName.value == null || 
 userName.value.length == 0
```

To

```
!userName
```

And for

```
userPassword.value == undefined || 
userPassword.value == null || 
userPassword.value.length == 0
```

To

```
!userPassword
```

And it will evaluate everything to empty strings (`""`), `NULL`, `undefined`, `false`.

```js
document.getElementById("register-user").addEventListener("click", register);

function register() {


  let userName = document.getElementById("user-name");
  let userPassword = document.getElementById("user-password");

  if (!userName.value) {
     console.log("Please provide user name");
  }
  else if (!userPassword.value) {
      console.log("Please provide user password");
  }
  else {
      console.log("Everything is fine. You can register user.");  
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="user-name" placeholder="Enter User Name" />
<br /><br />
<input type="password" id="user-password" placeholder="Enter User Password" />
<br /><br />
<button id="register-user">Register</button>
```

Thus by using an **exclamation mark** (`!`) you get more flexibility to change for a variety of range of user input.