# How to add a "Email sent" element under form after submitting?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, web

I am making a mail form in html that submitts values to a php sendmail file. When I submitt the form Id like a little box to popup, Ive seen it on other websites but cannot figure out how to do it myself. My form looks like this :

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" id="name" name="Name" placeholder="Namn" required /><br />
            <input type="text" id="email" name="TheEmail" placeholder="E-Mail" required /><br />
            <input type="text" id="phone" name="Phone" placeholder="Telefon" required /><br />
            <textarea id="message" name="Message" placeholder="Message" rows="8" cols="80" required></textarea><br />
            <button class="form-button" type="button" id="send-email">Send</button>
            <span id="response"></span>
        </form>
```

JS:

```
const btn = document.querySelector("#send-email");

btn.addEventListener("click", sendDataToBackEnd);

function sendDataToBackEnd() {
    //Write code to send data to your back end service.

    btn.textContent = "Processing..";
    btn.setAttribute("disable", true);
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.getElementById("response").textContent = "Email Sent";
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: fyi, `<br required />` is wrong. Submit your form via AJAX, handle the result/success in Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**AJAX**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) to communicate(send data) with your backend server.

While that data is sending, you can disable the button, so that no new request is being sent by the user again.

After you receive data from the server, display the message accordingly.

You can read here mode about how to send data using [**`fetch API`**](https://phpenthusiast.com/blog/javascript-fetch-api-tutorial) to PHP server

**Demo:**

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("#send-email");

btn.addEventListener("click", sendDataToBackEnd);

function sendDataToBackEnd(){
  //Write code to send data to your back end service.
  
  btn.textContent = "Processing..";
  btn.setAttribute("disable", true);
  setTimeout(() => {
     document.getElementById("response").textContent = "Email Sent";
  }, 2000);
}
```

```html
<form>

  <input type="text" id="name" name="Name" placeholder="Namn" required /><br />
  <input type="text" id="email" name="TheEmail" placeholder="E-Mail" required /><br />
  <input type="text" id="phone" name="Phone" placeholder="Telefon" /><br required />
  <textarea id="message" name="Message" placeholder="Message" rows="8" cols="80" required></textarea><br />
  <button class="form-button" type="button" id="send-email">Send</button>
  <br><br>
  <span id="response"></span>
</form>
  <br><br>
```

> Note: There is an error in your HTML code. `equired>/textarea><br />`, you are missing the `<` to close the **textarea** tag

Comment: I get this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at scripts.js:3"

Comment: @MaxK123 please update your code in the question, so that error can be figured out.

Comment: Ive updated the main  question now to the used code

Comment: The code is working fine, have you placed your ``scripts.js`` after the HTML code? I mean to say just before the closing of the ``body`` tag. @MaxK123

Comment: <html><head>//content of head tag lile meta and title tags</head><body> //your HTML code <script src="scripts.js"></script></body></html>  @MaxK123 this is how the structure should be, if you are placing your ``<script>`` in head tab then it will not work.

Comment: It works! But I can press the button without the required fields, how can I catch the values in my mail.php file? Ive updated my code in he question

Comment: You need to do form validation before sending data to the backend server. You can refer to this answer [form validation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65879060/11926970) and if it helps please upvote that answer too. @MaxK123

Answer (score 0):

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("#send-email");

btn.addEventListener("click", sendDataToBackEnd);

function sendDataToBackEnd(){
  //Write code to send data to your back end service.
  
  btn.textContent = "Processing..";
  btn.setAttribute("disable", true);
  setTimeout(() => {
     document.getElementById("response").textContent = "Email Sent";
  }, 2000);
}
```

```html
<form>

  <input type="text" id="name" name="Name" placeholder="Namn" required /><br />
  <input type="text" id="email" name="TheEmail" placeholder="E-Mail" required /><br />
  <input type="text" id="phone" name="Phone" placeholder="Telefon" /><br required />
  <textarea id="message" name="Message" placeholder="Message" rows="8" cols="80" required></textarea><br />
  <button class="form-button" type="button" id="send-email">Send</button>
  <br><br>
  <span id="response"></span>
</form>
  <br><br>
```

It works! Thanks!